# is_user_logged_in() undefined at shutdown in plugin context

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks

The function `is_user_logged_in()` is not available at shutdown (plugin context, not theme).

I want my plugin to run only (1) on front-end pages and (2) when the user is not logged in.

This works, but since it also runs on Divi builder front-end pages, I need to add `!is_user_logged_in`:

```
if (!is_admin()) {
    add_action('shutdown', function () {
        // Do some ob_start() and PHP_Tidy() stuff...
    }, 0);
}
```

Unfortunately changing my conditional to `if (!is_admin() && !is_user_logged_in())` fails with:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in...
```

**Edit** User Patrice says below that `shutdown` is too early to check for `is_user_logged_in()`. How could that could be? Shutdown is the last hook fired: *Before PHP execution is about to end*

[Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Comment: Please note that `is_user_logged_in` is a pluggable function and you could get a fatal error if you call it too early.

To solve this problem, you can wrap the login check within a function hooked to the init action. Please check this comment in the Codex :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/#comment-2209

Comment: Thanks Patrice, but I need my action to run at `shutdown`. Is that too early?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 1 - Does not work**

```
// Catch is_user_logged_in() value before shutdown

function is_user_logged_in_init() {
    $is_user_logged_in_init = is_user_logged_in() ?? false;
}
add_action('init', 'is_user_logged_in_init');
```

Leaving this here for my reference. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31792921/142233)

**Edit 2 - Works**

I found two ways to solve this:

1. Option 1 - Not recommended [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30135988/142233)

`include_once ABSPATH.'wp-includes/pluggable.php';`

2. Option 2 - Rewrite the script, i.e. Add `shutdown` action inside `init` action

```
function beautify_conditionals() {
    if (!is_admin() && !is_user_logged_in()) {
        add_action('shutdown', 'beautify_actions', 0);

        ob_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'beautify_conditionals');

function beautify_actions() {
    $html = ob_get_clean();

    $tidy = new tidy;
    $tidy->parseString($html, [
        'drop-empty-elements' => false,
        'drop-empty-paras' => false,
        'escape-scripts' => false,
        'fix-backslash' => false,
        'fix-style-tags' => false,
        'fix-uri' => false,
        'indent' => true,
        'indent-spaces' => 4,
        'join-styles' => false,
        'lower-literals' => false,
        'tab-size' => 4,
        'tidy-mark' => false,
        'wrap' => 0,
    ], 'utf8');
    $tidy->cleanRepair();

    $tidy = preg_replace('/<!DOCTYPE html>/', '<!doctype html>', $tidy);

    echo $tidy;
}
```